# How to select whole column on headerClick in Vaadin Table?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin, trying to figure out how I can implement column selection on headerClick in Vaadin (the expected result: i click on any column and it becomes selected, just like row).

Seems that it is not so obvious to do. Please, can anyone advice me on that issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can figure out which header was clicked with a [`HeaderClickListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html) and apply some custom style to the fields belonging to that category. But be wary of the sorting functionality and the number of rows & columns displayed. If there are too many, you may not want to redraw the whole table...

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What will be the use case for selecting a whole column? There might also be issues regarding lazy loading because table and grid components only load partial pages of the container to the browser.

Comment: @DavidHofmann One project I worked on had between the other requirements "_excel-like features_"

Comment: @DavidHofmann Yes, Morfic is right, it could be named as an "excel-like-feature". Actually, the requirement is to generate a table from uploaded .csv in browser with the possibility to select specific columns: a user is selecting output column ("sales", e.g.) and some factor columns ("advertising campaign costs", "labour costs", etc). So we decided to try Vaadin as it is well-known for it's high developing speed.

Comment: Then you can use the spreadsheet component as suggested in the edit of my comment

Comment: @DavidHofmann if you just want to select a few columns and do some sort of simple operation like exporting them to a file, the spredasheet may be overkill both in features and price. While the spreadsheet may do the trick, a simple workaround with a `HeaderClickListener` and some CSS may offer a viable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, There is no API to do that in the current Grid and Table components. But as @Morfic mentioned you can configure a HeaderClickListener and then you'll have to save the column clicked as a state somewhere and add a wrapper on top of your datasource collection to get the data of the column in a scalar valued list.

If you need Excel-like features please check out [Vaadin Spreadsheet component](https://vaadin.com/spreadsheet), it's a paid component but will work for you.