# How to add click listener or context menu to Vaadin's Grid column Header

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683490/how-to-select-whole-column-on-headerclick-in-vaadin-table). But I'm interested in Vaadin 14 as I am migrating old Table components to Grids. There no longer a **HeaderClickListener**. Therefore, how can you implement click listener on Grid header.

I don't mind adding a context menu with a column selection for copying, but as I understand it, there is no API to get data in a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vaadin 14 there is no HeaderClickListener. Instead you need to do something like this:

```
Column<MyBean> column = grid.addColumn(..)
HeaderRow headerRow = this.getHeaderRows().get(0); // Get first header row
Div component = new Div(); // Just example, anything that has click listener can be used
component.setText("Header");
headerRow.getCell(column).setComponent(component);
component.addClickListener(..);
```

Alternatively you can use GridContextMenu

```
grid.addColumn(..).setId("column");
GridContextMenu<MyBean> menu = grid.addContextMenu();
item.addMenuItemClickListener(event -> {
    Notification.show(selectedColumn);
});
menu.addGridContextMenuOpenedListener(event -> {
    // item is not present when clicking header
    if (!event.getItem().isPresent()) {
        event.getColumnId().ifPresent(id -> {
            selectedColumn = id;
        });
    } else {
        menu.close(); // Do not let menu open on body
    }
});
```

Comment: And in order to get the values ​​in this column, you need to walk through the children of the column?

Comment: If you mean actual values of the Items, they are not children of the column. Instead you need to walk through the data list and pick property of the selected column of each item.

Comment: I use alternative approach, but sometimes there is illegal reaction on right-click occured. It is when clicked in grid's item where is null or empty value. In this case 'event.getItem()' returns 'Optional.empty()' and unwanted context menu opened.