# Right click to copy cell content

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

Is there a way in a Vaadin grid to right click (open context menu) and copy the cell content?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: unforunately I have no idea how to handle this. The available GridContextMenu is not useable for a specific cell.

Comment: You are asking complex thing, that needs to spliced down to multiple questions perhaps. But start here to check how to get specific column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311746/how-to-add-click-listener-or-context-menu-to-vaadins-grid-column-header/68312451#68312451

What you mean by copying, copying to clipboard perhaps ? https://cookbook.vaadin.com/copy-to-clipboard